# How can I insert "child" entities with sequelize on create?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two entities:
order
orderItem

An orderItem cannot exist whitout an order, so the order_id is part of the orderItem primary_key.

I'm trying to create an order passing it in the creation object their orderItems.

This is my code:

```
Order.init({
  orderId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'order_id',
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  // some other fields...
}, {
  timestamps: false,
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'Order',
  tableName: 'orders',
});
```

```
OrderItem.init({
  orderId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'order_id',
    primaryKey: true,
    references: {
      model: 'Order',
      key: 'order_id',
    },
  },
  paymentRequestId: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'payment_request_id',
    primaryKey: true,
  },
  unitPrice: {
    type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    allowNull: false,
    field: 'unit_price',
  },
  finalPrice: {
    type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    allowNull: true,
    field: 'final_price',
  },
  quantity: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull: true,
  },
}, {
  timestamps: false,
  sequelize,
  modelName: 'OrderItem',
  tableName: 'order_items',
});
```

```
Order.hasMany(OrderItem, { as: 'items', foreignKey: 'order_id' });
OrderItem.belongsTo(Order, { as: 'order', foreignKey: 'order_id' });
```

So when I try this:

```
const orderObj = {
    currency: 'ARS',
    creatorUserId: 2,
    paymentRequest: {
      description: 'asd',
      // fields...
    },
    items: [
      {
        paymentRequestId: 90,
        unitPrice: 20,
        finalPrice: 40,
        quantity: 2,
      }
    ]
  };
try {

    const order = await dbSequelize.sequelize.models.Order.create(
      orderObj,
      {
        include: [
          {model: dbSequelize.sequelize.models.PaymentRequest, as: 'paymentRequest'}, 
          {model: dbSequelize.sequelize.models.OrderItem, as: 'items'}
        ]
      }
      );
      return res.json(order);
    } catch (er) {
      console.log(er);
    }
```

The error I get is this:

```
ValidationError [SequelizeValidationError]: notNull Violation: OrderItem.orderId cannot be null
```

What should I do in order to sequelize includes the generated orderId for each item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate `orderId` instead of `order_id` in associations in order to use a foreign key field properly:

```js
Order.hasMany(OrderItem, { as: 'items', foreignKey: 'orderId' });
OrderItem.belongsTo(Order, { as: 'order', foreignKey: 'orderId' });
```